# CSS div alignment like a puzzle

Tags: css

I'm trying to slot these divs togethor like a puzzle. I want to align div 4 between div 1 and 3.  As of now div 4 starts under div 3.  What is the solution, so that the divs "slot" into each other.

```
<div style='overflow:hidden;width:500px;'>
            <div style='float:left;width:200px;height:400px;border:1px solid #707070'>1</div>
            <div style='float:left;width:200px;height:300px;border:1px solid #707070'>2</div>
            <div style='float:left;width:200px;height:400px;border:1px solid #707070'>3</div>
            <div style='float:left;width:200px;height:300px;border:1px solid #707070'>4</div>
            </div>
```

I don't want to use position absolute.  This is just an example.  The real code is in a loop and the content size is dynamic.

Comment: I think if you paint this is more easy to understand and propose an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JQuery Masorny](http://masonry.desandro.com/). CSS alone is not powerful enough to do this dynamically.